# How to access service declared in another compose file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have 2 docker compose files:

### first:

```
version: '3'
services:
  service1:
  ports:
  - "8081:8080"
  ...
```

### second:

```
version: '3'
services:
  service2:
  ports:
  - "8088:8088"
```

from `service2` I try to execute http request to `server1`:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://service1:8081/api/v1/test/": service1; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException:service1] with root cause
router    |
router    | java.net.UnknownHostException: resource.mng
router    |     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
router    |     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a external network if it doesn't exist -

   `$ docker network create service || true`
2. Define external network to both compose files (first & second) -

   ```
   .........
      ports:
        - "8088:8088"
      networks:
        - service

    networks:
      service:
        external: true
   ```
3. Do a `up -d` & now you should be able to reach service1 container with name `service1` from service2 container.

Similarly, you can also use the default network create by compose but it will prefix your current directory name to the network name defined. You can also use the host network mode but that's not suggested.

**Update 1 -**

- docker compose creates a default network with prefix directory name. 
  https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
- Recently in docker compsoe 3.5, they launched custom name feature. So in case you can use compose 3.5, you can opt for giving a custom name to your docker compose network. Compose will create a new network in case it doesn't exist.(**preferred**)
  https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#name-1

You can take a call depending on your requirement. If you are on shell, you can do below shell trick to make the compose create a network only if it doesn't exist & ignore if pre-created.
`$ docker network create service || true`

Comment: Is it possible to ask docker-compose create a network if it doesn't exist?

Comment: Updated my answer. Please have a look. If you can upgrade to compose 3.5, I guess that would be the best bet, use "https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#name-1".

Answer (score 1):

Two ways:

**1.**
 `Service1` and `Service2` should be in same network!!

`docker network create -d overlay --attachable my_net`

**first:**

```
...
  service1:
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
    networks:
      - net
  ...
networks:
  net:
    external: true
    name: my_net
```

**second:**

```
...
  service2:
    ports:
      - "8088:8088"
    networks:
      - net
  ...
networks:
  net:
    external: true
    name: my_net
```

in this case request will be `http://service1:8080/api/v1/test/`

**2.**
You are forwarding port to the host `- "8081:8080"`
Ip of docker host is **172.18.0.1** by default (check your `ifconfig`)

For this case request will be `http://172.18.0.1:8081/api/v1/test/`

---

**Answer** to the question "*Is it possible to ask docker-compose create a network if it doesn't exist?*":

Yes it possible.
In 'first' compose file:

```
version: "3.3"
...
...
networks:
  my_net:
    driver: overlay
    attachable: true
```

If you are running `docker stack deploy -c file.yml hello`
-> will be created network with name `hello_my_net`
If you are running `docker-compose up -d`
-> will be created network with name `directory-name_my_net` (name of directory where is docker-compose.yml file)

So pay attention to name of network.

Next services attaches to this network.

!Attention. Version of compose file should be >= "3.3"

Comment: Is it possible to ask docker-compose create a network if it doesn't exist?

Comment: Yes. I will edit my answer, because here is unable text formatting.